# How to set the distance from soft keyboard to EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, distance, android-softkeyboard

I have a problem with soft keyboard overlapping parts of EditTexts.

When I click my EditTexts the soft keyboard appears just below the text, which means that a part of the text box is not shown as the soft keyboard overlaps it.

Any ideas how to increase the distance between EditText and Soft keyboard?

Comment: Try encapsulating all your layout in a `ScrollView`

Comment: @ClaireG even simply wrapping it up in scroll view does not result the acquired result

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem wasn't caused by EditText, but TextViews that messed up the layout.

Comment: What happen to your Textview ? I have same problem can you give a solution?

Comment: @user1354603 - Please be more specific

Comment: A TextView was used as a label to an EditText. The problem was that the TextView had padding and the EditText did not, so they just weren't aligned.

Answer (score 2):

There will be certain Solutions available that some times works and some times not 
what I am using is working and will handle your scenario 
Use the following Step by step

1- Add Scroll view to your layout inside the main layout

2- get Its reference

3- now use the following code snippet

```
editTextField.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            v.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    /*if(Build.VERSION.SDK.equals("4.1.1")||Build.VERSION.SDK.equals("4.1.2"))
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {*/
                    scrollView.scrollBy(0, 150);
                    //}
                }
            }, 500);

        }
    });
```

when ever screen needs to adjust the overlay it will scroll up the screen

Comment: Your solution does not work for EditTexts that are located at the bottom of the screen where you cannot scroll anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Just Try this,

Add gravity Bottom in Edit text and provide padding bottom As you need.

```
 <EditText
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"

    ................

   />
```

Comment: Gravity bottom fixes it

Answer (score -1):

**Try this way**

***In your mainfest.xml***

```
<activity
            android:name="YourActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
```

Comment: I rather not use adjustResize as it does a non-appealing animation during the resize..