# Adding Margin between EditText and keyboard

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, adjustpan

So this question has been asked few times already in here in the past years and non of the solutions worked for me.

The problem is that when I use `AdjustPan` to move the softkeyboard it hides part of the `EditText` as follows:

[image]

The solutions I tried are:

[Solution 1 (2011)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558810/adjustpan-not-preventing-keyboard-from-covering-edittext)

[Solution 2 (2014)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441372/how-to-add-margin-between-edittext-and-soft-keyboard)

[Solution 3 (2013)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658359/how-to-set-the-distance-from-soft-keyboard-to-edittext)

Most of the answers include using `AdjustPan/AdjustResize` so I will just say that none of them give the desired solution (Showing the whole `EditText` when keyboard is opened).

I was thinking maybe in 2019 there is a working solution for this problem.

The xml for this layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    tools:context=".ChatActivity">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuView
        android:id="@+id/actionbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorGrayBox"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_This"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
        android:text="@string/ActivityChat_This"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/actionbar" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/v_Line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:background="@color/colorLightGray"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_This" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/imagecard"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/actionbar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ivPersonPic"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@null" />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/assistant_bold"
        android:textColor="@color/colorLightPurple"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/actionbar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imagecard"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_Messages"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraint2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/v_Line"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraint2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_Message"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/et_rounded"
            android:fontFamily="@font/assistant"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:hint="@string/ActivityChat_Type"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textPersonName"
            android:paddingEnd="32dp"
            android:paddingStart="32dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.85" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib_Send"
            style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_chats_send"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.1" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorWhite"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/btm_nav"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/btm_nav"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.08"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_btm_nav" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Do you have the hole layout in a ScrollView? could you maybe post the Layout?

Comment: Can i see your xml file?

Comment: Try to set paddings to your `EditText`, and add `layout_height = "wrap_content"`

Comment: padding works but it make the text inside the EditText shifted towards the bottom which looks unsymmetrical

Comment: what about wrapping the whole layout inside a scroll view

Answer (score 5):

Try this, add this code in your `AndroidManifest.xml` activity

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Add the following into your root Layout at the `xml` file

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Answer (score 2):

First add **ScrollView** into your XML and add below lines into 
AndroidManiFest.xml in your **activity** tag where you use this search **EditText**.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan|adjustResize
```

Comment: This is same workaround or a hack repeated just like any other answer. Why not explain how keyboard works, why it is not possible in any other way. How keyboard knows where to show up...

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think your layout should be improved, there is no need to use two `ConstraintLayout` in a single xml file and the second one is a child of the first / main one. The idea behind this view is to flatten your whole layout, so as first step I think you should get rid off the second `ConstraintLayout`.

I've create a simple layout which looks a little like yours in order to test if my implementation will work, so here is the layout file:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/edit_text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:hint="Text"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textPersonName"
        android:paddingStart="32dip"
        android:paddingEnd="32dip"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_send"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_send"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="SEND"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#c5c6c7"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The structure looks similar to yours, at least the part with the `BottomNavigatioView`, `EditText` and the `Button`. Adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to the `Activity` which holds this layout will give this result (tested on a few devices) :

[image: screenshot 01]
[image: screenshot 02]

Answer (score 0):

In your `Layout` file add the following line in the `Constraint` tag.

```
android:isScrollContainer="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of problems with the keyboard myself, but I prefer using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` so you can handle the changes yourself. You should add a windowInsetsListener to your root view and if you don't have a transparent navigation bar the `systemWindowInsetBottom` should only be the keyboard. So you can just add padding to the container you're interested in. This is an example I use:

```
rootContainer.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener { view, windowInsets ->
    var containerPadding = 0
    if (windowInsets.systemWindowInsetBottom > 0) {
        val bottomBarHeight = bottomBar.bottom - bottomBar.top
        containerPadding = windowInsets.systemWindowInsetBottom - bottomBarHeight
    }

    if (containerPadding < 0) {
        containerPadding = 0
    }

    contentView.bottomPadding = containerPadding

    return@setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener windowInsets.replaceSystemWindowInsets(windowInsets.systemWindowInsetLeft, windowInsets.systemWindowInsetTop, windowInsets.systemWindowInsetRight, 0)
}
```

This way you can move the container above the bottomBar up (which has your `EditText` in it).

For me this was the best option I've found so far. Most options rely on GlobalLayoutListeners and see how much it changes, but this is far more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `EditText` view with a `TextInputEditText` view and simply add padding to its bottom, like:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    ...
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:paddingBottom="30dp"
        ...
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:hint="@string/txt_hint_add_comment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add padding bottom to TextInputLayout

Answer (score -1):

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraint2"
```

**Add** padding bottom in ConstraintLayout like android:paddingBottom="8dp"

**Remove** android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" from **Edittext** and **Imageview**
i.e. android:id="@+id/et_Message" and  android:id="@+id/ib_Send"

**Then rerun again**

Answer (score -1):

i had exact same issue and solved this problem forever with a 'easy implementation' and 'tested' method..the idea is that when the edit text gains focus scroll view auto scrolls to bottom.let me show you how...

first you should use nested scroll view as parent of main layout

second add a library to find out when keyboard opens

```
implementation 'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:2.0.1'
```

third add this class to your project

```
public class KeyboardUtil {
private View decorView;
private View contentView;
//a small helper to allow showing the editText focus
ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener onGlobalLayoutListener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        Rect r = new Rect();
        //r will be populated with the coordinates of your view that area still visible.
        decorView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

        //get screen height and calculate the difference with the useable area from the r
        int height = decorView.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
        int diff = height - r.bottom;

        //if it could be a keyboard add the padding to the view
        if (diff != 0) {
            // if the use-able screen height differs from the total screen height we assume that it shows a keyboard now
            //check if the padding is 0 (if yes set the padding for the keyboard)
            if (contentView.getPaddingBottom() != diff) {
                //set the padding of the contentView for the keyboard
                contentView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, diff);
            }
        } else {
            //check if the padding is != 0 (if yes reset the padding)
            if (contentView.getPaddingBottom() != 0) {
                //reset the padding of the contentView
                contentView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            }
        }
    }
};

public KeyboardUtil(Activity act, View contentView) {
    this.decorView = act.getWindow().getDecorView();
    this.contentView = contentView;

    //only required on newer android versions. it was working on API level 19
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        decorView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(onGlobalLayoutListener);
    }
}

/**
 * Helper to hide the keyboard
 *
 * @param act
 */
public static void hideKeyboard(Activity act) {
    if (act != null && act.getCurrentFocus() != null) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) act.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(act.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}

public void enable() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        decorView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(onGlobalLayoutListener);
    }
}

public void disable() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        decorView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(onGlobalLayoutListener);
    }
}

public static void adjustResize(Activity activity, final NestedScrollView scrollView) {
    KeyboardVisibilityEvent.setEventListener(
            activity,
            new KeyboardVisibilityEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean isOpen) {
                    // some code depending on keyboard visiblity status
                    if (isOpen) {

                        //Scroll view scrolls bottom without changing focus
                        View lastChild = scrollView.getChildAt(scrollView.getChildCount() - 1);
                        int bottom = lastChild.getBottom() + scrollView.getPaddingBottom();
                        int sy = scrollView.getScrollY();
                        int sh = scrollView.getHeight();
                        int delta = bottom - (sy + sh);

                        scrollView.smoothScrollBy(0, delta);


                    } else {
                        //Toast.makeText(context, "keyboard is close", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            });} }
```

then use it in your activity like

```
new KeyboardUtil(activity,nestedScrollView);
KeyboardUtil.adjustResize(activity,nestedScrollView);
```

and if you are in fragment you can pass below code as activity:

```
(AppCompatActivity)context
```

Answer (score -1):

There is one trick to do it:

1- put the EditText inside a CardView

2- style the CardView to looks like a TextEdit

3- add these properties to the  `EditText`

```
android:paddingBottom="15dp"
android:paddingTop="15dp"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```